# How to translate 债权 and 债权转让 into English?

Tags: translation

How to translate the Chinese 债权 and 债权转让 into English?

I guess 债权 has a meaning opposite to the word 'liability'. For example,
money deposited with a bank becomes a liability of the bank. But for the depositor, it has the right(债权) to gain the interests.

Comment: 债权 iciba：[律] creditor's rights; obligatory right; right in personam; claim in personam 
债权转让：iciba：释义：[经] assignment of debt; equitable assignment
find many example sentences at jukuu

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is focused on finding English words to express the meaning of Chinese terms that are already known, and thus is more suited to a site about English.

Comment: Translation from Chinese to English is not off-topic and these two accounting words are not well translated in some Chinese-English dictionaries, such as iciba or dict.cn. Searching the words in simplefiled-Chinese can not get the answer from .tw. So it has a value for others to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the 國家教育研究院 (of taiwan, in traditional chinese) maintains a bilingual academic terms database.

http://terms.naer.edu.tw/download/

in 會計學, you may download the zipped excel file,

http://terms.naer.edu.tw/download/101/Term_101.zip/

that you may find:

債權移轉　subrogation
債權，求償，索賠　claim

have fun :)